# Java - List of objects. Find object(s) with a certain value in a field

Tags: java, list, contains

I have two lists of objects. The objects in each list are different subclasses of the same class.

I want to look at objects in list One, check the value of a particular field, and then see if there is/are any objects in list Two that have the same field value. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Option A) Use `Iterables.any` from [Google guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/index.html).  Option B) Use nested for-loops.

Comment: It's hard to answer if someone asks for "a best" way. Do you want the most performant, the most readable, the most simple, the shortest, the most beautiful solution? Do you have huge list, do you expect to do this lookup thousands of times or just once?

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is more correct. This is the simplest, easiest solution to implement.

```
for(TypeA itemA : listA) {
    for(TypeB itemB : listB) {
        if(itemA.field == ItemB.otherField) {
            //Do Whatever
        }
    }
}
```