# Error: incompatible types Object Could not be converted [ArrayList]

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist, error-handling, syntax-error

I am getting a compiler error in my for loop declaration: `incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Type2`

I am trying to do this : [Java - List of objects. Find object(s) with a certain value in a field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11477195/java-list-of-objects-find-objects-with-a-certain-value-in-a-field)

Here is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Test2 {
    String name;
    int value;
    public ArrayList list = new ArrayList<Test2>();

    public void q() {
        for(Test2 w : list) { // Here is the error: 'incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Test2'
            if(w.value == 10)
                System.out.println(w.name);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `public ArrayList<Test2> list = new ArrayList<Test2>();` or just cast the list in the `for` loop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a raw type and why shouldn't we use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java has no way of knowing to expect an object of type `Test2` in the list; you need to parameterize it. Either explicitly declare `list` as `public ArrayList<Test2> list = new ArrayList<Test2>();`, or cast it in the loop: `(Test2 w : (ArrayList<Test2>)list)`.